# Using resolve in angularfire2

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angularfire2

I am trying to use route resolve in my angularfire2 project. I have a blog page with list of blogs.

blogs-resolve.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Blog } from '../../shared/models/blog';
import { FirebaseService } from './firebase.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';

@Injectable()
export class BlogsResolve implements Resolve<Blog> {

  constructor(private firebaseService: FirebaseService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any>|Promise<any>|any {
    return this.firebaseService.getBlogs().map(blogs => {
      console.log(blogs)

      blogs;
    }).first();
  }
}
```

The `getBlogs()` from `firebaseService` returns the list of blogs. And the above `console.log` gives the array of objects i.e. no of blogs I have.

But in the component when I try to console log the data, it shows `undefined`.

blogs.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import {FirebaseService} from '../../shared/services/firebase.service';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { Blog } from '../../shared/models/blog';

export class BlogsComponent implements OnInit {
  blogs: Blog[];

  constructor(
    private firebaseService: FirebaseService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.forEach((data: { blogs: Blog[] }  => {
      console.log(data.blogs)
  })
 }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Are you returning the blogs inside the map? `return blogs;`

Comment: @echonax my mistake... Thank you

Comment: Problem solved?

Comment: @echonax The current problem is solved but not the whole problem. Since before using resolve, I fetched the blogs from the service and while doing so, in the browser the text was shown first and then the images, which didn't look so good. Then I decided to use resolve but it didn't change either. The rendering is the same as it was before. Do you have any idea why is that?? Thanks